# How do I install the Sun/Oracle Java SDK on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, java, sdk

Since 11.10 Ubuntu does not provide the `sun-java-jdk`, how do I install it?

Comment: [Here's](http://strug.wordpress.com/2009/02/22/installing-java-7-snapshot-on-ubuntu/) a quick tutorial for installing JDK7 on Ubuntu.

Comment: I have it in this post http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=19446284&postcount=62

Comment: One other problem with openJDK (at least coupled with Nvidia cards) is when using Java2D, transparency is extremely slow, while with Sun it is blazing fast.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

**NOTE**: *Some of the contents of this answer might have become obsolete and there are some comments where people have reported problems. You're advised to read through the comments first.*

--

### Ubuntu 11.10 Oneric

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-plugin
```

[[Source](http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/09/14/how-to-install-jdk-on-ubuntu-11-10/)]

### Ubuntu 12.04 Precise

Clean up the historical open jdk:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
```

Add a new repo and install the sdk:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

If you want the JRE and the browser plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

[[Source](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-oracle-javajdk-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-11-10-oneiric)]

### Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) - another way

Thanks to the comments, please note that you can try this method too: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

### Make the sun java the default

You may want to also add the following

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You should get the following

### Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status

0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java       1         auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java       1         manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java   1         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2

Select (2) and press enter

Now running:

```
java -version
```

Returns:

java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)

Comment: @Renaud I've approved the edit, in case somebody runs into the same issues.

Comment: Is there any up to date repo?

Comment: @PawełPrażak: there is no point in downvoting when you didn't find what you expected... yet, I've edited the answer with a *seeminlgy* working solution for Ubundu 12.04. I cannot test it right here, please tell us if it works or edit the post with a wokring solution.

Comment: @JMax sorry, but I'm not sure what do you mean, the thing is that this repo contains 1.6.0_26 - it's outdated and have lots of unfixed security issues. But anyway I\ve found a almost perfect solution, see below :)

Comment: I get a bad error with these instructions for 12.04: sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.

Comment: @JayTaylor: are you sure your download worked properly? did you try it all over again? This kind of error is more likely a partial or incorrect download

Comment: This failed for me as well. Same error. Nightmare.

Comment: @JayTaylor do not use ppa:eugenesan/java, it's broken. ppa:webupd8team/java works fine.

Comment: on 11.10 sudo apt-get update returns this `W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2EA8F35793D8809A
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`

Comment: To install on 12.04, this was the only way I could do it: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Comment: This is terrible I wish I had read the comments, I wish I could downvote... please fix this. :(

Comment: @z7sgѪ: please note that instead of complaining you can edit the answer, it will be peer reviewed and if relevand approved. This way, this (very old) answer will remain up-to-date.

Comment: I needed to install oracle jdk 1.6 on lubuntu 12.04 and none of the provided PPA's worked. Didn't want to mess with binary installers so i just used `add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/java` and then replaced 'precise' with 'oneiric' in synaptic. So now I have 1.6.0_26 on precise - not the latest but enough for me.

Comment: The 12.04 way also works on 12.10

Comment: Looks like eugenesan/java is some really-really nasty ppa. First of all it is broken. Even if I remove it from Software Center, it does not go away! I tried to purge it as well, still no luck. Had to reinstall the OS.

Comment: @JMax please remove this answer, as other people says its toxic!

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli: I've changed my answer to a community wiki. Feel free to edit and complete it if you think this is necessary

Comment: For those who corrupted your system, this link might be of your help http://askubuntu.com/a/126419/24203

Answer (score 13):

There is very good page on official [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java). There you can find all recommended methods. I've used this [excellent automatic script](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6).

Make sure git is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

### Sun/Oracle Java 1.6.0

Build local debs:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/master/oab-java.sh
chmod +x oab-java.sh
sudo ./oab-java.sh
```

Script will build packages from source and place them in local repo, then they can be installed e.g.:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-fonts sun-java6-source
```

You can see all available packages in `/var/local/oab/deb`

Remember to select the right version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

To setup everything else (like browser plugin, keytool, etc.) you can use this (it will be a long list!):

```
sudo update-alternatives --all
```

The script is a wrapper for [this Debian script](https://github.com/rraptorr/sun-java6), if you're curious ;)

### Oracle Java 1.7.0_51

There is an [Issue 123](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/issues/123) currently in OAB and a [pull request](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/pull/125)

Here is the patched vesion:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/ladios/oab-java6/master/oab-java.sh
chmod +x oab-java.sh
sudo ./oab-java.sh -7

sudo apt-get update
sudo sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk oracle-java7-fonts oracle-java7-source
```

Read more on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/173951/11547)

Comment: Nothing.[x] Installing Java build requirements failed
[i] Showing the last 5 lines from the logfile (/home/me/oab-java6.sh.log)...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
3135's retcode: 100
failed

Comment: You might want to file a bug report https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/issues

Comment: `wget https://raw.github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/master/oab-java6.sh` says ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: Works for me, check: https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/blob/master/oab-java.sh

Answer (score 4):

You can install the official package from Oracle :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u1-download-513651.html

choose linux as your platform

Comment: Supplemental instructions for 12.04 available here: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/