# How do I upgrade Sun Java (JRE) on Ubuntu 11?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade, java

On Ubuntu I've installed the Sun JRE from `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu oneiric` and am at Version 6 update 26. (Outlined in the accepted answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/353983/how-do-i-install-the-sun-java-sdk-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneric))

I downloaded the bin file for Version 6 update 31 but don't know how to update Ubuntu to use it.

I tried running the bin file which ran fine, but `update-alternatives --config java` tells me there's only one `java` installed in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java`.

Is there some tutorial somewhere that goes through the upgrade process?

Answer (score -1):

How-to for JRE 6 update 31 (32/64 bit version) for ubuntu.

> http://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java

cheers.

Comment: I'd note that should that link go down, your answer would be useless. You may want to edit in essential information into your answer as a result